# iphone: integration with exchange server

Tags: iphone, exchange-server

Can you tell me how can I synch the data from my application like notes, calendar events etc. to exchange server.

wondering if we have an API for microsoft exchange

I am looking for consuming exchange web services

Please enlighten me on this.

Regards
Ankit

Comment: HI Ankit Sachan,  have you find the solutions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options

- [Exchange Web Service API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710.aspx)
- [ActiveSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499(v=EXCHG.80).aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please help me here to sync exchange server contacts in iPhone app.